# Joyent Node.js The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation

Tags: visual-studio

i have installed nodejs manually and from visual studio 2015 installation , but every time i check for apache cordova dependency cheker i get

Joyent Node.js The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation

Answer (score 3):

Same issue.  I had installed Node.js version 6.9.1 manually.  After uninstalling via Windows (Control Panel->Programs and Features->NodeJs->Uninstall), I was able to go to Control Panel->Programs and Features->VS2015->"Change"->"Modify" and was given the option to install the Joyent version.  Prior to the uninstall, Joyent nodejs was not an option when trying to Change/Modify VS2015.